# How can I conditionally include a nonexistent file in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using Visual C++ to build and test a project, but I'll also be using it on other platforms. I started the code initially on a different platform.

In some of my class headers I need to include a file which is specific to the other platform, however, this file doesn't exist in the Visual C++ workspace.

I've tried using code like this:

```
 #if TARGET == OTHERPLATFORM
 #include "themissingfile.h"
 #endif
```

where TARGET is defined elsewhere as WINDOWS

```
 #define TARGET WINDOWS
```

However, I still get a compiler error stating that "themissingfile.h" cannot be found. It appears like the precompiler is processing the include before the if. What's the best way to get around this? I suppose I could just create a blank "themissingfile.h" in the Visual C++ source folder, but it seems to me like there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#define TARGET WINDOWS` does not set TARGET to the string WINDOWS: it sets it to whatever WINDOWS is defined to. Most likely this happens:

```
  #define WINDOWS          // Sets WINDOWS to 0
  #define OTHERPLATFORM    // Sets OTHERPLATFORM to 0
  #define TARGET WINDOWS   // Sets TARGET to 0

  #if TARGET == OTHERPLATFORM // Evaluates to 0==0, so true
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `_WIN32` macro instead:

```
#ifndef _WIN32
#include "themissingfile.h"
#endif
```

`_WIN32` is defined for both 32-bit and 64-bit builds. See [C/C++ Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: (Not my vote). This doesn't explain the problem, and isn't necessary. Frederik Slijkerman has the correct answer.

Comment: @MSalters, the OP is reinventing the wheel. There are existing macros that indicate compiler and platform. IMO, this provides a solution while, admittedly, does not explain the behaviour with the posted code.